# Switching activities (at the same time resetting text field) don't change smoothly

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm working on an android app. I created log in form in one activity and after log in it switches to another activity. I'm trying to reset EditText field while switching activity but while clicking on login button, it shows the edittext box before switching. It should switch smoothly, not showing the text box. Below my code, what can I do to make better?

package com.mtilab.blogspot.imtiapp;

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private TextView messageRef;
        private EditText usernameRef, passwordRef;
        private Button submitRef, signupRef;
         //user and pass for test case
        private String user = "admin", pass = "admin";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            messageRef = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loginTV);
            usernameRef = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameET);
            passwordRef = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordET);
            submitRef = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginB);
            signupRef = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registrationB);


           //submitref is ref of login button
            submitRef.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(View vw){
                            if(usernameRef.getText().toString().equals(user) &&
                                  passwordRef.getText().toString().equals(pass)){

                  Intent userIntent = new   Intent(MainActivity.this, User.class);
                                startActivity(userIntent);

                                usernameRef.setText("");
                                passwordRef.setText("");
                                messageRef.setText("");
                            } else{
                                messageRef.setText("U R Not You!");

                                passwordRef.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        }

        // way 2 , when login button pressed
        /*public void onClickLoginButton(View view) {

            messageRef = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loginTV);
            usernameRef = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameET);
            passwordRef = (EditText)findeViewById(R.id.passwordET);

            if(usernameRef.getText().toString().equals(user) &&
                    passwordRef.getText().toString().equals(pass)){

                Intent userIntent = new Intent(this, User.class);
                startActivity(userIntent);

                usernameRef.setText("");
                passwordRef.setText("");
                messageRef.setText("");
            }else{
                messageRef.setText("U R Not You!");

                passwordRef.setText("");
            }

        }*/

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to clear the `EditText` if login is successful? Maybe you can call `setText("")` before `startActivity()` and check.

Comment: I tried in that way but still it shows the cleared text field before switching activity. It should switch smoothly and clear part should be done internally. Takes may be millisecond but it shows empty box!!

Answer (score 1):

You can hide all Views before starting the next activity:

```
submitRef.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View vw){
                 if(usernameRef.getText().toString().equals(user) &&
                              passwordRef.getText().toString().equals(pass)){

                    usernameRef.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    passwordRef.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    messageRef.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    // you might want to keep that
                    usernameRef.setText("");
                    passwordRef.setText("");
                    messageRef.setText("");

                    Intent userIntent = new   Intent(MainActivity.this, User.class);
                    startActivity(userIntent);

                 } else{
                    messageRef.setText("U R Not You!");

                    passwordRef.setText("");
                 }
            }
     }
);
```

Using `View.INVISIBLE` will just hide the View, but it will still occupy space in the layout. If you do not want that, use `View.GONE`.

For more info, see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29).

Comment: Not perfect but View.INVISIBLE works better than before.

Comment: If you want it to look even better, you could use 1) a fadeout-animation  and 2) an AnimationListener and then in "onAnimationEnd()" you can start the new activity